# How to make VCPKG copies dependencies pdb files in output directory

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, pdb, vcpkg

I have multiple "internal" library which I'm trying to manage with vcpkg+cmake.
Generally speaking everything is working properly.
I have only one minor issue which I can't solve.
When working in Windows with MSVC compiler I can't have the pdbs of my internal dependencies copied along with the dlls.

The dependencies have the `vcpkg_copy_pdbs()` in the portfile and they properly export the pdbs in the local cache `..\build\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\debug\bin` along with the dlls.
It just miss the final step to have them copied where the executable files is placed so that dependencies symbol can be load.
Note that the dependecies dlls are copied from the local cache to the output directories and the program starts properly. Also the pdb of the project itself are in the output directory. Only the pdb of the dependecies are missing.
What is the proper way to handle this?
It seems strange to me that vcpkg handle everything and then it just miss the final copy.